# Can not get Email from Facebook in Android

Tags: android, facebook, email, android-facebook

I tried to use below code to get my facebook email address via my app, but return value is null.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
private CallbackManager callbackManager;
private Button fb;
private LoginButton loginButton;
private AccessToken accessToken;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    callbackManager = CallbackManager.Factory.create();

    fb = (Button) findViewById(R.id.fb);
    loginButton = (LoginButton) findViewById(R.id.login_button);

    callbackManager = CallbackManager.Factory.create();
    LoginManager.getInstance().registerCallback(
            callbackManager,
            new FacebookCallback < LoginResult > () {
                @Override
                public void onSuccess(LoginResult loginResult) {

                    accessToken= loginResult.getAccessToken();

                    GraphRequestAsyncTask request = GraphRequest.newMeRequest(AccessToken.getCurrentAccessToken(), new GraphRequest.GraphJSONObjectCallback() {
                        @Override
                        public void onCompleted(JSONObject user, GraphResponse response) {
                            final Profile profile = Profile.getCurrentProfile();

                            if ((user != null) && (profile != null)) {

                                accessToken = AccessToken.getCurrentAccessToken();

                                if (accessToken.getDeclinedPermissions().isEmpty()) {


                                    try {
                                        String email = user.get("email").toString();
                                        Log.e("facebook response email",email+"mm");
                                        Log.e("facebook response",user.toString()+"mm");
                                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                                        e.printStackTrace();
                                    }


                                }


                            }
                        }
                    }).executeAsync();

                }

                @Override
                public void onCancel() {
                }

                @Override
                public void onError(FacebookException exception) {
                }
            }
    );

}

public void onClick(View v) {
    if (v == fb) {
        LoginManager.getInstance().logInWithReadPermissions(
                this,
                Arrays.asList("email","public_profile")
        );
    }
}

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    callbackManager.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    accessToken = AccessToken.getCurrentAccessToken();
    if (accessToken != null) {
        Log.e("Token", "Token: " + accessToken.getToken());
        Log.e("UserID", "UserID: " + accessToken.getUserId());
    }
}
```

}

I wrote some code but result is null?
How i can get email from Facebook SDK?
I don't know what the reason, but I can get email address using Graph API explorer. Is there anybody know what is wrong with this code?

Comment: You need to specify which fields you want

Comment: I want token and e-mail from Facebook .That's all @WizKid

Comment: I know. When you do the request to Facebook you have to specify which fields you want. Otherwise Facebook will not return them to you

Comment: How i can solve my problem in your option ? @WizKid

Comment: You specify that you need the email field and Facebook will give it back to you

Comment: org.json.JSONException: No value for email @WizKid

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/155279/discussion-between-baggio-and-wizkid).

Comment: Yes. Because you are not telling Facebook that you want the email field so they are not returning it to you.

Answer (score 0):

To retrieve email, you have to explicitly setReadPermission on the email address of the user. So please insert the following line in your code after you have initialized the loginButton

```
loginButton.setReadPermissions("email");
```

It should start returning the email Id after that.

All the best!!

Comment: I think problem is in this line logInWithReadPermissions

Comment: @Baggio - You do not need to set a LoginManager if you are setting the LoginButton. LoginButton has LoginManager built into it. So you do not need 2 buttons. One login button is fine. Also you have not registered the callback into your LoginButton but to a separate LoginManager instance. Please simplify your code - use only the FB login button, no need for an extra button or a LoginManager instance.